# Finding local extrema using both single derivative test and double derivative test

Tags: calculus

I get these 2 so confused so I am trying to use both of them with the same problem. I am able to solve it with single derivative but not double:

$f(x) = x^5 - 5x + 3$

single Derivative calculations
$f'(x) = 5x^4 - 5$
$x = 1, -1$

Plugging 1 and -1 into f(x) provides me with:

local max = $(-1, 7)$
local min = $(1,-1)$

Double derivative calculatons:
$f''(x) = 20x^3$
$f''(1) = 20(1)^3 = 20$
$f''(-1) = 20(-1)^3 = -20$

local max = $(-1, 20)$
local min = $(1,-20)$

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone tell me step by step how to solve each way? Thanks!

Comment: The first derivative is the slope and the second is the acceleration of the slope

Comment: the second derivative is not the acceleration of the slope.

Comment: Just wondering how you made out on this problem?

Comment: I figured it all out. Thanks for checking back!

Comment: Great, glad to hear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that there are two ways to do something, one way with the first derivative and another way with the second derivative. Rather, optimization is a single process, a process that involves using both the first derivative and the second derivative in sequence.

You calculated the first derivative correctly. You correctly solved for the critical values of $x$, namely $1$ and $-1$. You correctly evaluated $f$ at those critical values. By this point you have keyed on two $(x, f(x))$ pairs: $(-1, 7)$ and $(1,-1)$.

But I don't see how you knew that $f(x) = 7$ was a local maximum and $f(x) = -1$ was a local minimum. Typically we use the second derivative test for that. (But you drew this conclusion before evaluating the second derivative at the critical values of $x$.)

Moving to your second derivative calculations, you calculated the second derivative correctly. You evaluated the second derivative correctly at both critical values of $x$.

Because $f^{\prime\prime}(-1)$ is negative at the critical point $x=-1$, that shows that $x=-1$ is a local maximum.

Because $f^{\prime\prime}(1)$ is positive at the critical point $x=1$, that shows that $x=1$ is a local minimum.

Thus we have found all the critical values (using the first derivative) and evaluated them (using the second derivative). We now know all of the local maxima and minima of the given function.